# SQL Server 2008 - Create From and To Date from Single Date Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

To start the table I'm dealing with has inconsistency as there are blank tenant values something I cannot control (vendor will take time to fix it). Also the date columns are `varchar` as that how it's in the actual table. Again something I cannot control and for the purpose of the report to pick the max date, the date columns need to changed from char to date. The database is running on SQL Server 2008 so cannot use LEAD function

I have a `@rent` table variable as below which holds the tenant rent charged values. I.e every time a tenant rent is updated\changed it gets applied in the `@rent` table. In certain cases the rent can be updated multiple times in a day or changed in the future if teams find incorrect rent was applied (notice the created `date_sql`). The `Date_changed_SQL` indicates when the rent is actually applied. `DATE_CHANGED_SQL` column will be used to create `From` to `To` columns.

In most cases there will be a duplicate `DATE_CHANGED_SQL` but based on the `CREATED_DATE_SQL` and time of the latest `TOT_DEB_Val` needs to be selected

Sample data:

```
Declare @rent TABLE 
    ([R23_SQL_ID] int, [PROP_CODE] int, [TENANT_NUMB] varchar(5), [TOT_DEB_VAL] int, [DATE_CHANGED_SQL] varchar(10), [TIME_CHANGED_SQL] varchar(5), [CREATED_DATE_SQL] varchar(10), [CREATED_TIME_SQL] varchar(5))

INSERT INTO @rent
    ([R23_SQL_ID], [PROP_CODE], [TENANT_NUMB], [TOT_DEB_VAL], [DATE_CHANGED_SQL], [TIME_CHANGED_SQL], [CREATED_DATE_SQL], [CREATED_TIME_SQL])
VALUES
    (12080, 2524, '41673', 77.49, '2011-07-28', '04:42', '2013-03-19', '04:42'),
    (12081, 2524, '41673', 79.42, '2012-02-02', '04:42', '2013-03-19', '04:42'),
    (12082, 2524, '41673', 79.95, '2012-08-16', '04:42', '2013-03-19', '04:42'),
    (21819, 2524, '', 67.91, '2015-01-15', '09:39', '2015-01-15', '09:39'),
    (21820, 2524, '51500', 67.91, '2015-01-16', '', '2015-01-15', '09:45'),
    (31729, 2524, '51500', 67.91, '2016-08-08', '', '2016-08-08', ''),
    (31152, 2524, '51500', 193.48, '2016-09-05', '10:53', '2016-09-05', '10:53'),
    (34215, 2524, '', 89.86, '2017-03-14', '18:53', '2017-03-14', '18:53'),
    (34216, 2524, '53407', 89.86, '2017-03-15', '', '2017-03-14', '18:53'),
    (34260, 2524, '53407', 89.86, '2017-03-15', '12:32', '2017-03-20', '12:32'),
     (29461, 1589, '33659', 151.78, '2000-08-21', '19:00', '2016-08-16', '19:00'),
    (8356, 1589, '33659', 136.84, '2011-05-26', '04:42', '2013-03-19', '04:42'),
    (8357, 1589, '33659', 144.36, '2011-11-24', '04:42', '2013-03-19', '04:42'),
    (8358, 1589, '33659', 147.91, '2012-05-31', '04:42', '2013-03-19', '04:42'),
    (8359, 1589, '33659', 151.78, '2012-11-29', '04:42', '2013-03-19', '04:42'),
    (14502, 1589, '33659', 200.00, '2013-08-12', '08:30', '2013-08-12', '08:30'),
    (15476, 1589, '', 157.68, '2013-11-22', '09:49', '2013-11-22', '09:49'),
    (17846, 1589, '50602', 157.68, '2013-11-29', '14:00', '2014-05-21', '14:00'),
    (18548, 1589, '50980', 157.68, '2014-06-18', '', '2014-06-18', '13:21'),
    (18547, 1589, '50980', 160.69, '2014-06-18', '13:21', '2014-06-18', '13:21'),
    (20351, 1589, '51343', 160.69, '2014-11-07', '', '2014-11-05', '14:20'),
    (24096, 1589, '51343', 163.74, '2015-07-27', '07:34', '2015-07-27', '07:34'),
    (26286, 1589, '51343', 165.01, '2016-01-25', '08:59', '2016-01-25', '08:59'),
    (28168, 1589, '51343', 166.31, '2016-06-13', '11:02', '2016-06-13', '11:02'),
    (32751, 1589, '51343', 166.80, '2016-12-12', '08:52', '2016-12-12', '08:52'),
    (34058, 1589, '53386', 110.91, '2017-03-07', '', '2017-03-07', '08:22'),
    (34057, 1589, '53386', 110.91, '2017-03-07', '08:17', '2017-03-07', '08:17'),
    (34189, 1589, '53386', 110.91, '2017-03-07', '13:19', '2017-03-13', '13:19')
```

Requirement: I'm trying to create a view to show the rent period (`From` and `To`), the rent value per property and tenant as below

[Desired Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apB2B.png)

Comment: If you highlight the code component of your answer and the Code Sample button of the toolbar above the text entry area (the curly brackets button) you can format your code and make it much more readable.  Alternatively you can indent every line 4 spaces (which may be easier if you prepare your code in a text editor beforehand.

Comment: Hi John, havent used stackoverflow much, will try next time. I haven't got the solution yet and have created the desired result in excel. Hence uploaded the screenshot

Comment: It may be that my answer is better than I first thought. In your desired result set, is the penultimate row right? In all the others, the `to_date` is one day before the `from_date` in the following row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to be pretty close to what you want. You may need to adjust it a little. It doesn't quite give you the results as per your data set ... but it's pretty close and should give you something to work with.

```
/*cte assigns a row number to each entry, so we can join to the following row for that property*/
with cte as (
select 
    R23_SQL_ID,
    PROP_CODE,
    TENANT_NUMB,
    DATE_CHANGED_SQL,
    TOT_DEB_VAL,
    CREATED_DATE_SQL,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PROP_CODE ORDER BY DATE_CHANGED_SQL, TIME_CHANGED_SQL) as Seqn
from @rent
    --I wasn't sure about this where clause, you may want to get rid of it, but the results were closer to what you asked for with it in.
    where TENANT_NUMB <> ''
   )

select
    rentStart.R23_SQL_ID,
    rentStart.PROP_CODE,
    rentStart.TENANT_NUMB,
    rentStart.DATE_CHANGED_SQL as From_Date,
    --where you've got to the last row, I've put in "today" as the end date
    convert(char(10),isnull(dateadd(dd,-1,rentEnd.DATE_CHANGED_SQL), getdate()),121) as To_Date,
    rentStart.TOT_DEB_VAL,
    rentStart.CREATED_DATE_SQL
from
    cte as rentStart
    LEFT JOIN cte as rentEnd ON
        rentStart.Prop_Code = rentEnd .Prop_Code AND
        rentStart.Seqn + 1 = rentEnd .Seqn
where
    --Filtering to just the property you were showing
    rentStart.Prop_Code = 2524
    --This is the attempt to look only for the final change in the day. It may be better handled in the CTE rather than here.
AND (rentStart.DATE_CHANGED_SQL < rentEnd.Date_CHANGED_SQL OR rentEnd.DATE_CHANGED_SQL is null)
```

Comment: Did this help @Jag99 ? I'd be happy to look at this again with you if you can say what if anything is wrong. If you're happy with it as it is, please mark the answer as accepted.